# Monoogse findByIdAndUpdate is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update the user profile image uri but this is not working instead it give me the same document as it is

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  req.body.id,
  { profileImage: uri },
  { returnDocument: "after" },
  function (err, docs) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      res.status(400).send("Error updating image")
    } else {`enter code here`
      console.log("Updated User : ", docs)
      res.status(200).send("Image updated")
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Try `new: true` instead of `returnDocument: 'after'`

Comment: I think its issue with query, it should be `{ $set: { profileImage: uri } }`